# Rails ActionMailer w/ Devise + Google Apps in Development Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, devise, actionmailer, google-apps

I'm trying to configure ActionMailer to send mail from Devise in development mode with my Google Apps account. I've added the following to my config/environments/development.rb file, but it looks like mail is not being sent. Note: this is for Google Apps, not Gmail (but the Gmail servers should work -- they do in my mail client).

Anything jump out as strange in my config?

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "mydomain.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "myemaiL@mydomain.com",
    :password => "mypass"
  }
```

Comment: did you set config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true?

Answer (score 0):

We're using all the same settings successfully with our Google Apps account (and Devise) -- the only difference is that we're using "plain" for :authentication.

A slight difference -- we're using this in production and sort of on our staging environment (there we send email, but all to a test email address rather than to users).  On development we just look in the rails log to debug emails...

But one thing you might check: I was testing using GMail on a macbook that had been set up with MacPorts, but with ruby/rails and other stuff set up using rvm and Homebrew and was getting SSL exceptions in this environment -- when I set `:enable_starttls_auto => false` the error stopped, but no mail was sent.  I think there was a conflict between the libraries installed by MacPorts and the ones used by Rails.

Not sure if that helps :-)